# How to Search Amazon using Multiple ASIN in Product URL

Tags: http, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Previously, I've successfully used the following URL structure to search Amazon by ASIN:

https://www.amazon.com/s?k=B00DAG60A0+%7CB00DTXA578+%7CB00CIVO9R4+%7CB009SZ2P4C+%7CB00962GUEI

In the past this returned expected results - one product representing each ASIN in URL. However, this no longer works and Amazon either returns a single product for all ASIN(s) or even worse may return message:

> No results for..

I tried replacing the `'|'` with the `OR` operator but unfortunately the results are the same.

Interestingly, if I search for a single ASIN I get the expected result but when I string together multiple ASIN I get 1 matching product or no results at all.

Is there a way to manipulate the HTTP request / URL structure so that Amazon returns search results matching each ASIN in search query? Any search operators I'm unaware of?

Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue now, any luck?

Answer (score 1):

That is because only two of the asins you specified are still available.

For the url you provided I got the two results.